# Extracting coordinates from JsonObject in android

Tags: java, android, json

I'm getting Json Array with different Objects and extract them into variables.
But one of them is being  bit more difficult for me:
- **"query": "Lat -34.88 and Lon 174.76"**

From this object I would like to be able to extract the Latitude and Longitude.
I know how to extract a String with a start and end value but the problem I'am having is that the coordinates length changes, depending on the data received.

Basically I only need to extract the Latitude, starting after "Lat" plus the space, ending at "and" minus the space. And then again for the Longitude, starting at "Lon" plus the space...

Could anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a regular expression:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Lat ([-0-9.]*) and Lon ([-0-9.]*)");
        checkMatch(pattern, "Lat 34.8.2 and Lon -174.2"); 
        checkMatch(pattern, "Lat -34.4 and Lon 174"); 
    }

    private static void checkMatch(Pattern pattern, String latAndLong) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(latAndLong);
        System.out.println(matcher.matches());
        System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); 
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    }
}
```

## Output

```
true
Lat 34.8.2 and Lon -174.2
34.8.2
-174.2
true
Lat -34.4 and Lon 174
-34.4
174
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.split(regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to split the query String.

```
    String query = "Lat -34.88 and Lon 174.76";
    String[] split = query.split(" ");
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(split[1]);
    double lon = Double.parseDouble(split[4]);
    System.out.printf("Lat: %s. Lon: %s", lat, lon);
```

Output:

```
Lat: -34.88. Lon: 174.76
```